# Why does my exported Mac app not communicate to the Leap Motion?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, leap-motion

I have a Leap Motion Mac app which uses the libLeap.dylib library. When run within Xcode, my project works perfectly, but when I export my app it runs (in the console I see all is working) except I don't get any values from my Leap Motion.

I think maybe the library is not linked or something like that. I'm just quite new to Mac app development. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you included the dylib in the Resource Bundle? If the library isn't provided by the system you must deliver it with your app. But before doing that check if it is allowed to ship the library with your app.

Comment: Yes, its in Resource Bundle. How can i deliver it?

Comment: If it's in the bundle, you already deliver it with the app when exporting it as an *.app-file.

Comment: If it wasn't linking you'd know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common cause of this is sandboxing. If your Mac application is sandboxed on export, you need to make sure that "Allow Outgoing Connections" is enabled under the Network section of your sandboxing permissions.

The Leap client communicates with your Mac application via a network connection, so you have to make sure that your sandboxed application allows this connection. Otherwise, your application will quietly fail to connect to the Leap controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a copy files build phase for `libLeap.dylib`?

While coding my app I was able to run in debug mode, but after archiving it crashed on launch due to missing the dylib...